# Random UIImage artefacts

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a very strange bug which appears randomly amongst users. In most cases, the same image loaded into a UIImageView shows perfectly, but occasionally has an artefact line running through it as in the pic attached. We cannot reproduce during testing on either the simulator or device. The image loaded is a simple png:

```
groupAvatarIV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(horizontalMargin, 5, 70, 70)];
groupAvatarIV.clipsToBounds = YES;
groupAvatarIV.layer.cornerRadius = 70 /2;
groupAvatarIV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar"];
[contentV addSubview:groupAvatarIV];
```

I am really out of ideas how to debug this - any tips would be appreciated please.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the project which we took over contained multiple image files with the same name, which is what caused the artefacts.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the image contains data for a width greater than itself, so it keeps writing data in an address that becomes the next line down etc... (evidenced by the fact that it starts at the widest part of the circle)

maybe there is something wrong with the params on the image, or it might just be an apple bug...

if it is an apple bug, I would expect it to be with the behavior of `clipToBounds`

try to collect OS info from the users that experience it... also you could try to re-save the images using a different program, like use ffmpeg to save them as a tiff, then convert back to png (which should be a lossless route), so you know it had to re-interpret it...

Answer (score -1):

You have mentioned that you have added the imageView in another view as a subview. It seems that the image view is not fit to the  superview. You need to check the frame size of both views. Then you need to set the frame of the image view equal to or less than the superview.